# Why does the same shared library show up multiple times when using `info proc mappings` in gdb?

Tags: linux, process, gdb, shared-libraries

When I open up a binary in gdb and enter `info proc mappings`, I get the following results:

```
gdb$ info proc mappings
process 26732
Mapped address spaces:

    Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
     0x8048000  0x804a000     0x2000        0x0 /gpfs/main/path/to/binary
     0xb098000  0xb09a000     0x2000     0x2000 /gpfs/main/path/to/binary
     0xb09a000  0xb09b000     0x1000     0x3000 /gpfs/main/path/to/binary
     0xb09b000  0xb0bd000    0x22000        0x0 [heap]
    0xb4d25000 0xb4efc000   0x1d7000        0x0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
    0xb4efc000 0xb4efd000     0x1000   0x1d7000 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
    0xb4efd000 0xb4eff000     0x2000   0x1d7000 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
    0xb4eff000 0xb4f00000     0x1000   0x1d9000 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
    0xb4f00000 0xb4f03000     0x3000        0x0
    0xb4f61000 0xb7fcc000  0x306b000        0x0
    0xb7fcc000 0xb7fcd000     0x1000        0x0 /gpfs/main/path/to/library.so
    0xb7fcd000 0xb7fce000     0x1000        0x0 /gpfs/main/path/to/library.so
    0xb7fce000 0xb7fcf000     0x1000     0x1000 /gpfs/main/path/to/library.so
    0xb7fcf000 0xb7fd1000     0x2000        0x0
    0xb7fd1000 0xb7fd4000     0x3000        0x0 [vvar]
    0xb7fd4000 0xb7fd6000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
    0xb7fd6000 0xb7ffd000    0x27000        0x0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
    0xb7ffe000 0xb7fff000     0x1000    0x27000 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
    0xb7fff000 0xb8000000     0x1000    0x28000 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
    0xbffdf000 0xc0000000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
```

Why is each shared library and the binary itself broken up into multiple, adjacent sections of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line represents a separate `PT_LOAD` segment:

```
$ eu-readelf -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
[…]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0213d8 0x0213d8 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x022000 0x0000000000022000 0x0000000000022000 0x1471d8 0x1471d8 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x16a000 0x000000000016a000 0x000000000016a000 0x04ba08 0x04ba08 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x1b6648 0x00000000001b7648 0x00000000001b7648 0x005218 0x0091b8 RW  0x1000
[…]
```

Typically, these segments have different sharing properties and permissions (read-only, read-execute, or read-write).  Different link editors can produce different numbers of load segments for the same shared object. For example, using the [`-z separatecode` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dz-keyword) tends add another load segment.